# When exporting facebook messenger data, is it possible to convert the filename into datetime?

Tags: facebook, unix-timestamp, epoch

I am not sure if this is even possible. I have used the export feature on FB to download Messages and all of the file names are basically a long string of numbers. I've searched all over the web to see if there is a way to decode the file name from FB Msgr files. I am trying to get the Date and Time of when the file was sent from a file name.

As an example, here is one of the file names: "17571372_428718127480452_853371653_o_428718127480452.jpg"

I've tried an Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tool on each of the sections of numbers with no luck. I happen to know what time and date this specific file was sent, but not the others that I have. SO I am using it as a baseline. The time and date is Mar 26, 2017 5:17:15pm.

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Why would the URL contain a timestamp?

Comment: I apologize. It is not the URL. I used the export feature to download messages. All of the pictures and files came with file names like the one I listed in the post. SO this is a file name.

Comment: Why would the file name contain a timestamp?

Comment: Hum, that is a good question. I guess I have to own that I had made an assumption.

I had found this https://towardsdatascience.com/download-and-analyse-your-facebook-messenger-data-6d1b49404e09

and assumed that it did have the time stamp in the data. I just happened to download the HTML version and wanted to see if I could figure out how to convert the file names.

Do you know if it does or does not have the timestamp?

Comment: If I would guess I would guess there is a message that contains a file and the message says when it was sent. And then it just reference the file.